# Can't connect my Redmi Note Pro 10 phone to my HP laptop via USB cable

Tags: usb, files, android, hp

Smartphone connection problems Redmi Note 10 pro  (English translation from Google):

Hi, I have very serious problems connecting my smartphone in question via usb on hp laptop. With Ubuntu as soon as I connect the USB cable to the PC the connection is connected / disconnected continuously. For a moment I see the memory on the phone desktop, a second later it disappears and then reappears and disappears infinitely. The phone is as new as the usb cable.

Tested OK on two different Windows PCs. I'm only having problems with this laptop I'm writing from (purchased for a month). The USB ports of the laptop in question are functional (tested with other smartphones and hard drives) no apparent problem. How could I solve it?

> Salve,  ho problemi molto gravi di connessione del mio smartphone in
>   oggetto via usb su pc portatile hp. Si con windows 10 che con Ubuntu
>   appena collego il cavo usb al pc la connessione si collega / scollega
>   di continuo. Per un attimo vedo la memoria sul desktop del telefono,
>   un secondo dopo scompare per poi ricomparire e scomparire all'
>   infinito. Il telefono è nuovo come il cavo usb. Provato su due
>   differenti pc windows in cui funziona alla grande. Ho problemi solo in
>   questo portatile da cui sto scrivendo (acquistato da un mese). Le usb
>   del portatile in questione sono funzionanti (testate con altri
>   smartphone e hard disk) nessun problema apparente. Come potrei
>   risolvere?
>
> Grazie

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]